# How do I extrude inwards instead of outwards?

Tags: modeling, faces, extrude

[image]How do I extrude something inwards instead of extruding it outwards?

[image]

Comment: Instead of 'invert' do you just mean extruding inwards?

Comment: Yeah that would be the one, sorry i am not only new to blender but totaly brand new to 3D modelling and animation. I have only started doing this just before christmas :) thanks for your patience :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you select the faces you want to extrude, then press E to extrude and simply drag inward, if you want to inset instead (second picture) press I and then scale by dragging with your mouse. Remember that instead of dragging, in both cases you can type a number so that you tell blender the "amount" of that action that you want.
See the pictures below for the differences.

**Extruding inwards:**
[image: Inwards]

**Insetting:**
[image: Inset]

Comment: Thanks i did think it was just dragging in instead of out and that obviously is how it works but for me when i drag in it do's nothing not like the above picture anyway :) obviously something i am doing as i ama newbie to 3D modelling. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Press the "E" key first.

Comment: no problem, keep in mind to press E before dragging as Dontwalk said, else you wil drag the faces witohut actually creating any new ones, that's what extruding and insetting do, they create new geometry.

Answer (score 1):

When you make an extrusion of a region of faces, the default direction for the extrusion is in or out along the average normal of the faces in the region, depending on the direction of drag.

When extruding a ring all around a sphere, (these spheres are Z-up) the first example below shows the faces moving in the direction of their average normal.. not what you want.

[image]

The way Blender gives you more options is:

- First, <kbd>E</kbd> make the extrusion
- Then, right-click, to leave the extrusion where it is
- Then, in a separate operation, transform the faces in the way you would like.

The second example shows the result of using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, (shrink / fatten) after right-clicking.

The third example shows the result of <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> (scale in XY, not Z) after right-clicking.

Note that you can get a result just like the second example by using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> instead of <kbd>E</kbd>, and choosing 'Along Vertex Normals'